# Consider a measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For each $j = 1, 2, · · · , n$, let $π_j :

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lebesgue-measure

Consider a measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For each $j = 1, 2, · · · , n$, let $π_j : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n−1}$ be the $j$-th map $(x_1, · · · , x_n) \to (x_1, · · · , \hat{x}_j, . . . , x_n)$, where $\hat{x}_j$ indicates that the $x^j$-th coordinate is taken out. Prove that $$|E| \le \prod_{i=1}^{n} |π_j(E)|^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$$

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What does $||E||$ mean?

Comment: Sorry,  and I have edited it. It should be |E| which means the Lebesgue measure of E.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy. I suspect that you do know that the proposer is using an incorrect notation $\|E\|$ for the measure of $E$.

Comment: Have you tried covering $E$ with collections of $n$-cells?